# .map function of Dataset returns list instead of dictionary

Tags: numpy, librosa, huggingface, huggingface-datasets

If I write a function:

```
def load_audio(example):
    filepath = example["audio"]["path"]
    arr, sr = librosa.load(filepath, sr=16000)
    return {'audio': {'path': filepath, 'array': arr,'sampling_rate': 16000}, 'sentence':example['sentence']}
```

and then call map for a dataset:

```
dataset = dataset.map(load_audio)
```

and

`print(type(dataset_dict['train']['audio'][0]['array']))`

gives

`<class 'list'>`.

I would expect the last one to give **numpy array**, why its type is a **list**?

This how I created the dataset:

```
sentences=list(transcript_dict.values())
audio_files=list(transcript_dict.keys())
audio_list = []
for file in audio_files:
    audio_dict = {
        "path": file,
        "array": np.array([]),
        "sampling_rate": 16000
    }
    audio_list.append(audio_dict) 
data = {'sentence': sentences, 'audio': audio_list}
dataset = Dataset.from_dict(data)
```

Even before mapping, it gives that the type of "dataset['audio'][0]['array']" is a list. Why it is not an array?

When I check:

```
print(type(audio_list[0]['array']))
```

it gives that it is of type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: Why should it give a dictionary? You just looped over all the examples, anf for each example you have a dictionary. So the result should be a list of dictionaries.

Comment: Exactly, I just changed the question. I want array from audio to be a numpy array, not a list, because librosa returns an array not a list

Comment: the problem is `map` returns a `map` object. Perharps you should consider using `np.fromiter(your_map_object, your_type)`

Comment: I just added that even before mapping, it returns a list instead of an array

Comment: Probably because its a list. We cannot help if we do not have access to the dataset. You are the only one with the access. And why do you expect it to be an array? Was it loaded in as an array? You can convert to the datatype you want as long as the conversion is allowed

Comment: I posted the code how I created the dataset. It is an initial dataset, with two columns: sentence and audio. Audio is a dictionary. And array of audio is an empty np.array. Way it gives that it is a list?

Comment: AttributeError: 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'dtypes'

Comment: But I show how I am creating the dataset. Sentences is a list of strings, and audio_files is a  list of strings. They can be empty strings. So path is a dummy string, and array is an empty array, but a NUMPY array. No pandas here. Sampling_rate is always equal to 16000, it can be dummy too. It is not about the values, it is about the type.

Comment: What's the `Dataset` import? Yes it does look like `audio_list` is a list of dict with an `array` field.  But `Dataset` might well make some changes.  Some comments assume it, and `map` are plain python or `pandas`.  We don't seem to know anything about this `Dataset` class.

Comment: ChatGPT: "It seems that the issue is because the from_dict method of the Dataset class automatically converts lists to numpy arrays only for the top-level keys. However, it does not recursively convert nested lists to numpy arrays.". You can experiment with any dummy dataset, if one of its features is a dict, with one element numpy.array, when using from_dict, it will convert that to a list.

Comment: s=['a','b','c']
a=np.array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
data2 = {'sentence': sentences, 'audio': audio_list}
dataset2 = Dataset.from_dict(data2)
print(type(data2['audio'][0]['array']))
print(type(dataset2['audio'][0]['array'])), will give: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'list'>

Comment: It seems like from_dict method converts numpy arrays to list?!

Comment: It is solvedwith: dataset.set_format(type='numpy', columns=['audio'])